# Why is bundle overwriting itself

Tags: java, android, bundle

I´m sending result to previous activity

```
public void sendResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Bundle result = new Bundle();
    switch (who) {
        case TARIF:
            result.putParcelableArrayList(MainActivity.PICK_TARIFF_LOG, tariffList);
            break;
        case CALL_LOG_ALL:
            //  myCallLogList = myCallLog.unsortList(sortedCallList);
            if (usedDataCall) {
                result.putBoolean(IS_PICK_DATE, usedDataCall);
                result.putIntegerArrayList(PICK_DATE, date);
            } else {
                result.putBoolean(IS_PICK_DATE, usedDataCall);
            }
            result.putParcelableArrayList(PICK_CALL_LOG, myCallLogList);
            break;
        case SMS_LOG_ALL:
            if (usedDataSms) {
                result.putBoolean(IS_PICK_DATE, usedDataSms);
                result.putIntegerArrayList(PICK_DATE, date);
            } else {
                result.putBoolean(IS_PICK_DATE, usedDataSms);
            }

            result.putParcelableArrayList(PICK_SMS_LOG, mySmsLogList);
            break;
    }
    if (getParent() == null) {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    } else {
        getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    }

    intent.putExtras(result);
}
```

But my bundle result is overwriting and i dont see the reason why. 
For example case CALL_LOG_ALL: it will add that usedDataCall value and afted that it will be overwrite with that arrayList and in the end that parcelableList will be add so that boolean value is missing, but i need all 3 values to be in this bundle. Any ideas what is wrong there?

Comment: how do you observe that the boolean value is missing?

Comment: also, stupid question: your constant do have different values, right?

Comment: Actually that was that problem. Was to lazy to type it again and after copy paste i changed only name....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was same value for both constants. Was to lazy to type it again and after copy paste i changed only name..